# Why bitcoind will shutdown after encryptwallet?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, encryption

As mentioned in the `bitcoin-cli` document for `encryptwallet` command, bitcoin daemon will shut down after encrypting a new or unencrypted wallet. My question is about the reason for shutting the node down?

Also, I want to create another bitcoin wallet and it's very strange if I need to start after adding a new wallet. [this pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/11678) tried to remove shutdown after encrypting a wallet. is it safe? and what's the best way to deal with this problem?

> encryptwallet "passphrase"
>
> Encrypts the wallet with 'passphrase'. This is for first time
>   encryption. After this, any calls that interact with private keys such
>   as sending or  signing
>
> will require the passphrase to be set prior the making these calls.
>   Use the walletpassphrase call for this, and then walletlock call. If
>   the wallet is already encrypted, use the walletpassphrasechange call.
>   Note that this will shutdown the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour has been resolved by [12493](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/12493). As stated by Andrew Chow in the pull request, this was previously done to:

> ...prevent the BDB environment from
>   writing unencrypted private keys to disk in the database log files, as
>   was noted here. This PR replaces the shutdown behavior with a CDBEnv
>   flush, close, and reopen which achieves the same effect: everything is
>   cleanly flushed and closed, the log files are removed, and then the
>   environment reopened to continue normal operation.
>
> To ensure that no unencrypted private keys are in the log files after
>   encrypting the wallet, I wrote this script to pull private keys from
>   the original wallet file and searches for these keys in the log files
>   (note that you will have to change your file paths to make it work on
>   your own machine).
>
> As for concerns about private keys being written to slack space or
>   being kept in memory, these behaviors no longer exist after the
>   original wallet encryption PR and the shutting down solution from
>   2011.